# One to many relationship at google app engine can't work?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, one-to-many, jdo, datanucleus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [one to many relationship in java google ap engine caused error ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494240/one-to-many-relationship-in-java-google-ap-engine-caused-error)

i have implement a system to save information about user .
So i have aggregation at my class so the user class has list from contact class ...etc
in the first page "test it's just for register the user just by phone number " that must save the user in database but this cause error when i deploye my project in Google app engine <   **500 server error**  >

and the other page for update the exist user who previously has been registered, so at this will add to the list which the user object has .

*user class*

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class User implements Serializable{
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

 @Persistent
public String userNumber;

 @Persistent (mappedBy = "userC")
 public List<Contact> UserContacts =new  ArrayList<Contact>();

 public void AddContact(String name,String number) {
     Contact C=new Contact();
     C.ContactName=name;
     C.PhoneNumber=number;
     this.UserContacts.add(C);   }
     }
```

*Contact class*

```
    @PersistenceCapable
public class Contact implements Serializable{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

     @Persistent
        public String ContactName;

     @Persistent
    public String PhoneNumber;  
             @Persistent
    public User userC; }
```

**this page cause register for the user test will get user phone number and sign up should create new user with this number** 
*test page*

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
```

public class Test extends HttpServlet {

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.getWriter().println("<html><body><form  method = \"POST\"     action=\"/signup\">" + "please enter ur number :"+"<h4><label>name :  <input name =  \"userphoneNUMBER\" type =  \"text \" size =  \"25 \" />  </label>"+"<p> <input type = \"submit\" value = \"Submit\" />"+ "</form></body></html>");

    }
}
```

**this page take the number to create user**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SignUP extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        String user_PhoneNumber=req.getParameter("userphoneNUMBER");
        User obj = new User();
    obj.userNumber=user_PhoneNumber;
    resp.getWriter().println(obj.userNumber );
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

        try {
            pm.makePersistent(obj);
        } finally {
            pm.close();

        } }  }
```

***this page to continue update value at user object who already exist***

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Testinfo extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.getWriter().println("<html><body><form  method = \"POST\" action=\"/saveinfo\">" +
                "<center> <h2>please fill this form :</h2> </br> "+
"<h4><label> ContactName :  <input name =  \"ContactName\" type =  \"text \" size =  \"25 \" />  </label>"
+
"<p> <input type = \"submit\" value = \"Submit\" />"+
                "</form></body></html>");
    }
```

}

**this  page to save the information which cause error and no value will save at app engine**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SaveInfo extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

        String ContactName = req.getParameter("ContactName");
        String ContactNumber = req.getParameter("ContactNumber");
                   PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Query query = pm.newQuery("select * from " + User.class.getName());
        List<User> list = (List<User>) query.execute();
        for (User obj : list) {


            if (obj.userNumber.equals("111")) {
                 pm.currentTransaction().begin();
                                     obj.AddContact(ContactName, ContactNumber);

                pm.makePersistent(obj);

                 pm.currentTransaction().commit(); }
            }
                          pm.close(); }  }
```

this  *111* for testing which i entered before as user phone number .

So how can i deal with lists and aggregation issues ??

**when going to update the user information this error occurred**

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Identifier expected at character 1 in "*" at         org.datanucleus.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:375)
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:230)
at sstooree.SaveInfo.doPost(SaveInfo.java:44)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
```

Answer (score 0):

by trying to change the query 
from

```
        Query query = pm.newQuery("select * from " + User.class.getName());
```

to

```
        Query query = pm.newQuery("select from " + User.class.getName());
```

that make the code work successfully without any error :)

Comment: You mean reversing the change you made by some uninformed person on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494240/one-to-many-relationship-in-java-google-ap-engine-caused-error

Comment: i have changes at my code 
by added the mapping to go with relationship one to many 
this link help me to get changes to my code 
finally by my old code i have * i try to remove it then i get it work 
"https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships"

Comment: at my old code i don't use mapping