# how to deal with datastore-indexes app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, jdo, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

for this example  [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494240/one-to-many-relationship-in-java-google-ap-engine-caused-error)  
i try to make it but this exception occurred ??

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="UserContacts_INTEGER_IDX" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

how can i write these indexes manually ?? i try to make WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml 
at this XML i write the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes  autoGenerate="true">

<datastore-index kind="Contact" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="UserContacts_INTEGER_IDX" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

but when Iam going to deploy this error stop me to continue deploying

*An internal error occurred during: "Deploying store to Google".
XML error validating*

So how can i get these indexes ??

**another issues >>** 
 when i run this code and add some properties at User class as

```
@Persistent (mappedBy = "userC")
 public List<Contact> UserContacts =new  ArrayList<Contact>();
```

and deploy it , the engine make indexes for the UserContacts  however appear Exception due to the new property - same error above can't make indexes to them  -

Comment: You are missing the closing </datastore-indexes>.

Comment: i added it , but still the same problem

Comment: Go to 'Datastore Index' section of the admin console and check if the index in question is actually 'serving'.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing for you to do is run you app locally and perform some test queries on those entities.
As you have `<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">` in your indexes config you should get a file called

```
WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml
```

in there you should get all the index definitions needed for your app to work.

Copy those index definitions to your `WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml` and update your app.

If you go to your cloud console and check on your Storage/datastore/indexes view you should be all those indexed either building or serving. Once all those indexes are on "serving" you should be good to go.